# OpenShift 4 error: Error reading manifest

Tags: docker, containers, openshift, podman, quay.io

during OpenShift installation from a local mirror registry, after I started the bootstrap machine i see the following error in the journal log:

```
release-image-download.sh[1270]: 
Error: error pulling image "quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-release@sha256:999a6a4bd731075e389ae601b373194c6cb2c7b4dadd1ad06ef607e86476b129": 
unable to pull quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-release@sha256:999a6a4bd731075e389ae601b373194c6cb2c7b4dadd1ad06ef607e86476b129: unable to pull image: 
Error initializing source docker://quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-release@sha256:999a6a4bd731075e389ae601b373194c6cb2c7b4dadd1ad06ef607e86476b129: 
(Mirrors also failed: [my registry:5000/ocp4/openshift4@sha256:999a6a4bd731075e389ae601b373194c6cb2c7b4dadd1ad06ef607e86476b129: Error reading manifest 
sha256:999a6a4bd731075e389ae601b373194c6cb2c7b4dadd1ad06ef607e86476b129 in my registry:5000/ocp4/openshift4: manifest unknown: manifest unknown]): 
quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-release@sha256:999a6a4bd731075e389ae601b373194c6cb2c7b4dadd1ad06ef607e86476b129: error pinging docker registry quay.io: 
Get "https://quay.io/v2/": dial tcp 50.16.140.223:443: i/o timeout
```

Does anyone have any idea what it can be?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here in the error:

```
... dial tcp 50.16.140.223:443: i/o timeout
```

Try this on the command line:

```
$ podman pull quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-release@sha256:999a6a4bd731075e389ae601b373194c6cb2c7b4dadd1ad06ef607e86476b129
```

You'll need to be authenticated to actually download the content (this is what the pull secret does).  However, if you can't get the "unauthenticated" error then this would more solidly point to some network configuration.

That IP resolves to a quay host (you can verify that with "`curl -k https://50.16.140.223`"). Perhaps you have an internet filter or firewall in place that's blocking egress?

Resolutions:

- fix your network issue, if you have one
- look at doing an disconnected /airgap install -- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/installing/installing-mirroring-installation-images.html has more details on that

(If you're already doing an airgap install and it's your local mirror that's failing, then your local mirror is failing)